# unexpected token error testing component with graphql

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js, graphql

I'm trying to test my components with jest. I'm using apollo client to query date from apollo server. I have follewed [apollo client docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-mutations) for testing queries, but without success.

I'm using nextjs and mongoDB with mongoose.

I'm getting this error:

```
 FAIL  components/organisms/createPost/CreatePost.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run
    Jest encountered an unexpected token
    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
    Details:
    /Users/eyub/Documents/Learning/Projects/lim/node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
```

here is my component

```
export default function CreatePost({}) {
  const [createPost] = useMutation(CREATE_POST, {
    refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_USER }, 'getUserData'],
  })
  const sumbitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    createPost({ variables: { text: event.target[0].value } })
    event.target[0].value = ''
  }

  return (
    <Component onSubmit={sumbitHandler}>
      <textarea placeholder="What's happening?" />
      <button>
        <Icon icon={'add'} />
      </button>
    </Component>
  )
}
```

here is my test:

```
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing'
import { CREATE_POST } from '@graphql/client/mutation'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import CreatePost from './CreatePost'

const newPostData = {
  text: '',
}

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: CREATE_POST,
      variables: {
        text: '',
      },
    },
    result: { data: newPostData },
  },
]

describe('<CreatePost />', () => {
  test('mocking test pass', () => {
    const component = render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <CreatePost />
      </MockedProvider>
    )
    component.debug()
  })
})
```

here my jest config:

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest')
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  // if using TypeScript with a baseUrl set to the root directory then you need the below for alias' to work
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
    '^@utils/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/utils/$1',
    '^@graphql/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/graphql/$1',
  },
  collectCoverageFrom: ['./components/**/*.{js,jsx}'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

Comment: What does your Jest config look like?

Comment: @juliomalves I have updated the post with the jest config, should jest config be knowing is dealing with graphql, is not enough with the provider on the test file?